# How to use an array variable as an argument in a powershell if statement

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, data-manipulation

As a part of a script for modifying a CSV, I am checking against a column **subCatDesc** to determine a **Team** based on predetermined values stored in an array.

```
$grocerySubTeams = "Grocery","Frozen","Bulk","Dairy"

function identifyTeam() {
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ($row.subCatDesc -contains $grocerySubTeams) {
        $row.team = "Grocery"
    }
  }
}
```

When running the script with this the **Team** column remains empty. However if I explicitly spell out what I want like below, it works.

```
function identifyTeam() {
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if (($row.subCatDesc -like "Grocery") -or ($row.subCatDesc -like "Frozen") -or ($row.subCatDesc -like "Bulk") -or ($row.subCatDesc -like "Dairy")) {
        $row.team = "Grocery"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried different comparison operators against the array instead of -contains, but none work.

Comment: Are you trying to compare one item to more than one, or more than one to one?

Comment: Try -in, in place of -contains

Comment: So the column **subCatDesc** can be either *Grocery*, *Bulk*, *Frozen*, or *Dairy*. If it matches any of those 4 items then the column **Team** should be set to *Grocery*. Does that clarify it for you?

Comment: Mark Wragg's suggestion fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @BryceJenkins `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators -ShowWindow`.  `-in` is for one-to-many, and `-contains` is its inverse

Answer (score 1):

It is the other way around:

```
  $grocerySubTeams -contains $row.subCatDesc
```

Comment: Actually just switching the comparison operator from **-contains** to **-in** like Mark Wragg suggested solved it, as I am comparing the values of $row.subCatDesc to the pre-defined array of $grocerySubTeams.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Mark Wragg in the initial comments of switching the comparison operator to **-in** resolved the behavior I was seeing.

```
if ($row.subCatDesc -in $grocerySubTeams) {
```

is the proper syntax for comparing the single value of the cell to the many items of the array.